# 60s/70s sci-fi book(s) with philosophical paradise

Tags: story-identification, books

This will definitely be a bit of a challenge to identify (to put it mildly), but my dad told me about a book he read as a teenager (13-14) that he found very philosophically meaningful, and still remembers to this day; I really want to track it down to see if I can find him a copy for his birthday, so I'll include all the details I have, in spite of their paucity.

It is a science fiction book, published some time before 1973/74 (which is when he read it). The book was paperback, and was part of a book series with at least four, five other books. He does not remember the author, but he knows (fairly convinced) that it was not Asimov or one of the greats, but a run-of-the-mill paperback science-fiction author.

The story had two distinct phases, and was set on Earth: there was a time before some extraterrestrials arrived, and a time after. In the time after, my dad remembers distinctly that the extraterrestrials helped Earth, and made it into a paradise to live in, and that there was a strong philosophical undercurrent in this description of paradise. There were very vivid descriptions of what life had become, and that there was no more death or suffering. He remembers no other plot points off the top of his head.

Like I said, a stab in the dark, and not a lot of information to go by, sorry! -- but I am sure that if he were asked specific enough questions, he could answer them "yes" or "no", and more information can be extracted from him :)

Comment: Makes me think of Clarke's "Childhood's End"

Comment: I also immediately thought about *Childhood's End*, except it isn't part of a series and *is* written by one of the greats,

Comment: A long shot is Piers Anthony's *Triple Detente*, where the Earth evolves into a paradise while administered by the alien Kazo, while the Kazo home planet becomes a paradise while administered by Earthmen. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/263431.Triple_Detente

Comment: @Andrew Childhood's End looks fantastic -- but after talking to my dad about it, it doesn't look like it's the one. I'll ask about Triple Detente later today!

Comment: Admittedly a very long shot: Keith Laumer's *The Monitors*.